# How can I check the connectivity in a Linq2Sql app so it doesn't freeze if it fails?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sqlconnection

So I've been using LINQ to SQL (dbml) for my C# projects for a bit now as it makes integrating SQL pretty easy for me.. the only thing is everything is so automated that I don't know how to actually edit things.

Using LINQ to SQL makes it so that it automatically connects to the database IP with user and pw in the connection string it creates in the config file but say the database isn't up.. or i want to change IPs.. the app freezes on start up.

How can I test for connectivity before having it automatically connect?  I can't seem to find where in the code it does this exactly.

Comment: windows phone app or regular web page?

Comment: you might consider using threads.

Comment: C# app.  and why am i getting downvoted??  it's a legitimate question...

Comment: well the LINQ to SQL feature pretty much does the automatic connectivity to the database for me.. so i just wanted to find a way to put a "check" first.. but i can't seem to find where my program does that

Comment: Heh, I just upvoted it back to 0 :(  Seems like a really good idea.

Comment: I don't think it's particular to linq, you can have the same issue even with ado.net when you open the connection. You don't know if the connection will open or not and you catch the exception after a timeout or other kind of exception in case of any problem connecting to db.

Comment: @AD.Net You are correct, however getting the SQL Connection from Entity Framework isn't straight forward, so this question is specific to doing both really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your settings for the Entity, I am rusty on Linq to SQL but think it is similar, are in the App.Config on the project where you CREATED you Linq to SQL model.  They are similar to this(using Entity Model):

```
    < connectionStrings>
    < add name="Example" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ExampleDB.csdl|res://*/ExampleDB.ssdl|res://*/ExampleDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ACTUALSERVER;initial catalog=ACTUALDATABASE;persist security info=True;user id=(SET USER HERE);password=(SET PASSWORD HERE);multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    < /connectionStrings>
```

The important part for connection is the connection string though:

```
&quot;data source=ACTUALSERVER;initial catalog=ACTUALDATABASE;persist security info=True;user id=(SET USER HERE);password=(SET PASSWORD HERE);
```

You can try to alter this to different connection strings if you want, and keeping the metadata the same.  For differenent environments like "Dev", "QA", "UAT", "PROD" etc...  And then copy and paste the connection block starting with the '< add name="' and till the end portion of 'providerName='(thing)' />.  Then just alter the connection string and give it a different name.  Then you could have the calling code use a different context or connection like:

```
using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
context.Connection = (new connection)

 (your data return method)
}
```

You may be able to do this directly in the constructor of your context(MyContext).  Cannot recall.  Generally I usually set up multiple configs "DEV", "QA", "UAT", "PROD" and have them build for different environments for a service.  You can build a connection string manually but dynamic connection strings can be a pain as you as a developer now need to ensure a few things:

1. The model of a Dev environment EXACTLY matches another with it's objects in your model.  If not goodbye code return.
2. If you are invoking a set user that you are ensuring that your user has rights on certain environments
3. That you are not putting the integrity of your code at risk by showing too much publicly for user settings.

Comment: ah i get it now.. it establishes the connection once i declare the datacontext..... i for some reason thought it was connecting on start up.  thank you very much.. the suggestion of using the "using(MyContext..." should work just fine

Comment: Stackoverflow IMHO lately have been overrun with people that like to diss more than help lately.  No problem, I would suggest thinking of using Entity Framework in the future too.  It creates more modeling for you to play with and the concept of 'POCO' classes to play with and is more robust when dealing with navigation of foreign keys and linking objects.  It has a tad more overhead but in the end IMHO I like it more.

Comment: ya.. i mean i understand if i'm asking a question wrong.. then help me format it correctly! i'm really asking for help here lol.  but yes entity framework is something someone suggested to me too.. so i think it's about time i learn that.  thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

(All assuming you're using Sql Server)

Expanding on [djangojazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23503933/209259).

```
public void TestDbConnection()
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    bool isAvailable = false;
    using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
      var connection = ((IObjectContext)context).Connection as SqlConnection;

      try
      {
        connection.Open();
        isAvailble = true;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
    }
    TestDbConnectionComplete(isAvailable);
  });
}

public void TestDbConnectionComplete(bool isAvailable)
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for this.  actually goes into specifics on to how to actually test the connection

Comment: i tried this but IObjectContext isn't recognized.. I thought it might be just ObjectContext but the casting errors too